# I need a way to make videos fast forward in cypress

Tags: cypress

I am testing a video player using cypress. I am using the below command to play the video:

```
cy.xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-root/div/div/alm-player-curriculum/mat-drawer-container/mat-drawer-content/alm-player-main/div/app-amp/div/div/button').click();
```

Then video is played successfully. How can I fast forward the playing of the video?

Answer (score 0):

With a video, there is the `playbackRate` property that can be used to
speed/slow down videos.

Here is the code in an example [repo](https://github.com/bahmutov/video-example/blob/79a332d5ba63c1f596c6ea36e850b00bbd14e033/cypress/integration/spec.js#L37-L48) by Gleb:

```
cy.get('video').then(($video) => {
    $video[0].playbackRate = 4
    $video[0].play()
  })
```